# How do I get the custom attribute value of an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How do I get the name value from the following?

```
<select id="product">
    <option name="name1" value="1">one</option>
    <option name="name2" value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

I tried this (adding .name to the end. .value works, .name doesn't)

```
var select = document.getElementById("product");
select.onchange = function(){
    var selectedString = select.options[select.selectedIndex].name;
    alert(selectedString);
}
```

thanks

Comment: "name" is not really a valid attribute for an `<option>` element.

Comment: @user2588945 Did the below answer help resolve your issue?

Answer (score 5):

Use `getAttribute` because `name` is not a valid attribute for option (so there is no `name` property for the option element which gets updated when you set its `name` attribute), hence you cannot get it from the `name` property (by accessing `elm.name`).

```
var selectedString = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name');
```

Better way would be to make it a `data-*` attribute and access it using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) (Not supported in older browser versions).

```
<select name="model" id="model">
    <option data-name="name1" value="1">one</option>
    <option data-name="name2" value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

and

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.name; //or this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-name')
```

Comment: +1, but some browsers do create DOM properties for non–standard attributes (e.g. IE) and also create attributes for non–standard properties.